# Communicating with a NRF24L01

Tags: python, pi-2, wireless, communication

I'm trying to send signals from one raspberry pi to another using a NRF24L01+ transmitter. I was able to get the code to run on both the receiving and send raspberry pi's , but I have ran into some issues. The sending pi says that a signal is being sent. On the receiving pi it says it is listening, but the raspi is not picking up the signal.

I started with the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB_GebqaGas but it would not work for me even though everything looked the same for me.

I later tried the examples that come with the lib_nrf24 file I download and I still ran into the same problem.

Does anybody have some experience that could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use Raspberry to communicate by nrf24l01 with Arduino with this library: [nRF24/RF24](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24). It contains libs for Arduino but also Raspberry Pi C++ and Python and some examples too. As far as I get, the examples for Rapsberry Pi C++ works well after  little adjustment.

Hard part is to proper setup both sides that can communicate each other. Every settings of nrf24 must be the same except addresses. Addresses must be mirrored, that the transmit address on one end must equals receive address on other end.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this blog: http://invent.module143.com/category/raspberrypi/

Check this tutorial out: http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/rpi-3-tutorial-13-wireless-pi-to-pi-python-communication-with-nrf24l01/

Follow the tutorial exactly, it worked for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.